# Fix for screen flickering during install

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation, lenovo, 22.04

I'm attempting to dual boot Ubuntu 22.04 with windows 11 on my Lenovo Yoga 7i (I7 11th Gen/16Gb/Iris Xe Graphics). While installing it I have screen flickering issues that practically make the installer unusable every time I move the mouse or click anything I also have no keyboard connectivity either meaning that I am unable to access the terminal. I've remade the installation media and It still continues to do it. I'm relatively new to Linux in general so I'm not fully sure the next steps.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I attempted dual booting Fedora 37 and Windows 11 on my Lenovo Yoga Slim 7 Pro and had similar issues to you. After entering the Fedora installation the screen started flickering like crazy and the keyboard did not work. After many hours of googling I finally found a solution! The solution requires an external keyboard to connect to the laptop.

**Step 1:** Although you experience screen flickering, you have to go through the installation. I noticed that the flickering mitigates if you lower the resolution. The lower you go in resolution the lesser the screen flickers.

**Step 2:** Once you are through the installation of the OS, open the terminal and head over to /etc/default/ in which you will find a file called grub. Open that file with super user (sudo) privileges and add the following line **GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="i915.enable_psr=0 i8042.direct i8042.dumbkbd"**
save and exit.[src1](https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/Lenovo-Yoga-Series-Notebooks/lenovo-yoga-slim-7-pro-intell-keyboard-doesnt-work-on-ubuntu-20-04/m-p/5087655?page=2)

**Step 3 (Ubuntu)**: You should now write sudo update-grub and go to step 4.

**Step 3(Fedora)**: Head over to /etc/ There you should have files called grub2.cfg and grub2-efi.cfg. If you have a UEFI system (my case) you want to execute the following command :

**grub2-mkconfig -o "$(readlink -e /etc/grub2-efi.cfg)"**
If you are not on a UEFI system, replace  /etc/grub2-efi.cfg with /etc/grub2.cfg. [src2](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/152222/what-is-the-equivalent-of-update-grub-for-rhel-fedora-and-centos-systems)

**Step 4:** Restart your system and you should be set.

As I understand, the problem is that the configuration of the grub file was incorrect and caused the screen to flicker and keyboard to not work. If anyone has an explanation of the how and why this "bug" occured, feel free to explain it :)

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'm using Ubuntu on Lenovo Yoga Slim 7 Pro 14IHU5 & had 2 issues - the screen flicker and keyboard not working. Both of them got fixed with your answer. 